# Using indexOf for HTML selection elements via getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom, indexof, getelementsbytagname

Attempting to remove items shown in selects from an array. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cycle4passion/gdr7yrsy/)

```
var allProbs = []; // This is defined elsewhere
var dropProbs = [];
var j;
var sel = document.getElementsByTagName("select")
var selarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(sel); // Convert nodelist to array
for (j = 0; j < allProbs.length; j++) {
    alert(allProbs[j] + " " + selarray.indexOf(allProbs[j]) ); // all -1 here???
    if (selarray.indexOf(allProbs[j]) == -1) {
        dropProbs[dropProbs.length] = allProbs[j]
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an easy code to debug, have you tried checking your selarray after you created it? see what's inside?

Comment: So you are surprised that no item of `allProbs` is a `select` element. But you don't provide the items in `allProbs`. Then we can't help.

Comment: thx Saar: added : alert(selarray[0]); which shows pop with [object HTMLSelectElement] so I interpret that as selarray is not making an array out of sel like it is expected ???

Comment: I don't understand the down voters here. The OP has a problem understanding some code, that's exactly what this site is for so why mark it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Array.prototype.indexOf*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.indexof) performs a strict equality after calling *toString* on the value to compare. You are dealing with host (DOM) objects, the result of calling their *toString* method (if they have one) is implementation dependent.

Have you tried:

```
console.log(typeof selarray[j].toString);
```

and if the result of that is *function*, calling it may return something like:

```
"[object HTMLSelectElement]"
```

or

```
"object"
```

or whatever else the browser developers thought was a good idea. But it will likely return the same value for every member of *selarray*.

You haven't shown what the values of *allProbs* are, but unless they are an exact string match for whatever `selarray[j].toString()` returns, you'll get `-1`, and if it does match, you'll always get `0` (i.e. the first one).

#### Edit

So based on values in *allProbs* being strings, you will never get a match as you are effectively looking for where:

```
allProbs[i] === selarray[j].toString();
```

where *selarray[j].toString()* always returns one of the values above (or something else).

You may be able to use [*Array.prototype.findIndex*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.findindex) (new method in ECMAScript 2015 so a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill) may be required), which is like *indexOf* but uses a function to determine the match.

Presumably you are trying to find the select element with a value that is equal to a member of *allProbs*, so you many need something like:

```
var index;
for (var j = 0; j < allProbs.length; j++) {
  index = selarray.findIndex(function(sel) {
    return sel.value == allProbs[j];
  })

  /* do stuff based on value of index */

}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
// Polyfill for Array.prototype.findIndex
if (!Array.prototype.findIndex) {
  Array.prototype.findIndex = function(predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.findIndex called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
}

var allProbs = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
var dropProbs = [];
var sel = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var selarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(sel);

for (var index, j = 0; j < allProbs.length; j++) {

    index = selarray.findIndex(function(sel){
      return sel.value == allProbs[j]
    });


    if (index == -1) {
        dropProbs[dropProbs.length] = allProbs[j];
    }
}
document.write('<br>dropProbs: ' + JSON.stringify(dropProbs));
```

```html
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="aaa" selected>aaa</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I get 'String' in the console

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle to simplify discussion

Comment: BTW, I'm not that happy with the polyfill, it's just the one on MDN and works OK but doesn't seem to exactly implement the ECMA-262 algorithm.